# Is there a worldwide applicable color-emotion chart?

Tags: color, color-theory

Colors are used to represent emotions; especially in advertising.

People have even come up with color-emotion charts like this one:

[image: color-emotion chart example]

Yet, depending on the country, some colors have different meanings... in one country (eg USA) *WHITE* represents *purity, cleanness*, while it the other county (eg China) it's the color to represent *mourning*.

Is there any color-emotion chart which is applicable worldwide ?

Comment: Just a caveat: a lot of these are highly dependent on context, so one shouldn't put too much weight onto these types of charts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the coolest infographic I've come across that fits your description. It's slightly unintuitive to extract information from, but it is a pretty interesting way to show the different interpretations of color in different cultures.
[image: Color Across Cultures]

Infographic via [visual.ly](http://visual.ly/what-colors-mean-different-cultures)

Comment: See also http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31526/should-a-multinational-website-background-color-be-a-conscious-choice and http://webdesign.about.com/od/colorcharts/l/bl_colorculture.htm